# Conversion failing for date formatting

Tags: sql, date, t-sql

I have an nvarchar(100) column which has a value ' 8/11/2022'.

I receive and error when trying to convert it to date...

```
select convert(date,[date],103)
from [Source].[TableName] s_p 
--Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 96
--Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have tried a number of different ways to approach but I can't find one to give me '08/11/2022'

```
select Date = REPLACE(LEFT([Date],10),' ','0')
from [Source].[TableName] s_p 
--Outcome  8/11/2022

select REPLACE([DATE],' 8/','08/')
from [Source].[TableName] s_p 
--Outcome  8/11/2022

select convert(nvarchar,[date],103) 
from [Source].[TableName] s_p
--Outcome  8/11/2022
```

The strange thing is when I copy and paste from the results grid then do a replace it works fine...

```
select REPLACE(' 8/11/2022',' 8/','08/')
--Outcome 08/11/2022
```

Please help me to get to '08/11/2022' or any single digit to having a leading 0.

Thanks, Will

Comment: Don't store dates as strings to begin with. Anything else just covers up a critical bug. This can't be solved with replacements. If you store strings instead of dates you have to ensure all strings have the same format. Right now you have no idea whether that's November 8 or August 11. You assume, but you can't know

Comment: BTW no repro. `select convert(date,'8/11/2022',103)` works fine. If you get an error it's because that text field contains some other, unexpected value. There may be a US-style value, eg `8/13/2022`. In fact, the table may contain US-style strings, not UK-style. Try with `101`. If no error occurs, the strings are US-style

Answer (score 1):

Different languages and cultures have their own formatting preferences around date values. Some places like `M/dd/yyyy`. Some places like `dd/MM/yyyy`. Or perhaps  `d-M-YYYY` (different separators and conventions around leading zeros). The point is it's not okay to go into a place and impose our own preferences and norms on that culture.

The SQL language is no different. It really is it's own language, and as such has it's own expectations around date handling. If you violate these expectations, you should not be surprised when there are misunderstandings as a result.

---

The first expectation is for date and datetime values to be stored in datetime columns. It's hard to understate how much of a difference this can make for performance and correctness.

---

But let's assume that's not an option, and you have no choice but to use a string column like varchar or nvarchar. In that situation, there is still an expectation around how date values should be formatted.

Any database will do better if you use a format which stores the date parts in order by descending length. For example, ISO-8601 `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sss[.fff]` This is important to allow greater than/less than comparisons to work, it can greatly help with indexes and performance, and it makes cast/convert operations to datetime values MUCH more likely to succeed and be accurate.

For SQL Server specifically, there are three acceptable formats:
`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sss[.fff]`,
`yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss[.fff]`, and
`yyyyMMdd`.

Anything else **WILL** have date values that don't parse as expected. Any string manipulation done to call the `CONVERT()` method should focus on reaching one of these formats.

With that in mind, and assuming `8/11/2022` means November 8 and not August 11 (given the 103 convert format), you need something like this:

```
convert(datetime, 
  right([date], charindex('/', reverse([date]))-1) -- year
  + right('0' + replace(substring([date], charindex('/', [date])+1, 2), '/', ''), 2) -- month
  + right('0' + left([date], charindex('/',[date])-1),2)  -- day
)
```

And you can see it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/lM8sVySh

Yes, that's a lot of code. It's also gonna be more than a little slow. And again, the reason why it's so slow and complicated is you jumped in with your own cultural expectations and failed to respect the language of the platform you're using.

---

Finally, I need to question the premise. As the fiddle above shows, SQL Server is perfectly happy to convert this specific value without error. This tells me you probably have more rows, and **any error is in fact coming from a different row.**

With that in mind, one thing to remember is a `WHERE` clause condition will not necessarily run or filter a table before a `CONVERT()` operation in the `SELECT` clause. That is, if you have many different kinds of value in this table, you cannot guarantee your `CONVERT()` expression will only run on the date values, no matter what kind of `WHERE` clause you have. Databases do not guarantee order of operations in this way.

The problem could also be some invisible unicode whitespace.

Another possibility is date formats. Most cultures that prefer a leading day, instead of month or year, tend to also strongly prefer to see the leading `0` in the first place. That the zero is missing here makes me wonder if you might have a number of dates in the column that were formatted by, say, Americans. So then you try to parse a column with values both like `02/13/2022` and `13/02/2022`. Obviously those dates can't both use the same format, since there is no 13th month.

In that case, best of luck to you, because you no longer have any way to know for certain whether 2/3/2022 means March 2nd or February 3rd... and trying to guess (by say, assuming your own common format) is just exacerbating the same mistake that got you into this mess in the first place.

It's worth noting all three of these possibilities would be avoided had you used DateTime columns from the beginning.

Comment: Appreciate the post and the advise. It is unfortunate when trying to convert one culture to another in sql however in this instance it is necessary of the back of a tender acquiring business in South America. I couldn't implement your solution however I did manage to find another one.

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to use LPAD to add 0 to string, then CAST() string as date if you want to change to date data type